# Python Lambda function for negative number

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I use a lambda function to convert a decimal negative number to binary two's complement. However the result is not a binary number.

My code:

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first number"))

if num1  < 0:
def tobin(x, count = 8):
     return "".join(map(lambda y:str((x>>y)&1), range(count-1, -1, -1)))
    num1 = tobin
print num1
```

Result:

```
Enter first number -5
<function tobin at 0x1f9c260>
```

The expected result should be 1011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first bumber:\t"))

def tobin(x, count=4):
    return "".join(map(lambda y: str((x >> y) & 1), range(count - 1, -1, -1)))
if num1  < 0:
    num1 = tobin(num1)
print num1
```

result:

```
Enter first bumber: -5
1011
```